# Generating a random number and putting it in a TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have created a class which generates a random number:

```
public class DataGenerator
{
    public void RandomHRValue()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int RandomNumber = random.Next(0, 100);
    }
}
```

I have then created a XAML file and put the following within the `Grid`:

```
<TextBlock Name="a" Text="" Width="196" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="183,158,138,56"/>
```

I haven't done anything to the `xaml.cs` file. How would I go about putting a random number into that `TextBlock` every 20 seconds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`DispatcherTimer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
public MainWindow()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
     timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 20);
     timer.Start();
     timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
}

void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     DataGenerator dg = new DataGenerator();
     a.Text = dg.RandomHRValue().ToString();
}
```

Also change method type to int:

```
 public int RandomHRValue()
 {
      Random random = new Random();
      int RandomNumber = random.Next(0, 100);
      return RandomNumber;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment due to my low reputation, but in response to the other answer, would it not be better to use the following?

```
        InitializeComponent();
        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer {Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5)};
        timer.Start();
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
```

If this is wrong, can you say why, so I, myself, can get some feedback (btw OP and I are working together on this)

Comment: @user2946329 How about this?

Comment: This is not wrong. Yes it can be better to use object initializer. If you can't  leave a comment you can suggest your way by editing my answer so if it was helpful the owner of the post or reviewers will approve your suggestion. This is the correct way in this scenarios. :)